# What determines size of interactive markers in RViz?

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, marker, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per the title: how does the size of interactive markers get calculated in RViz? In particular the markers for revolute joints and the large interactive marker in the `planning_components_visualiser` or `planning_scene_warehouse_viewer` instances of RViz.

Some of my robots get large diameter markers (for their joints), while others seem to have significantly smaller markers. I haven't been able to find any real pattern to this, or relation to something like min/max joint angles or speeds, but my sampling space could just be too small.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61707/what-determines-size-of-interactive-markers-in-rviz?/) by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like the markers are generated inside [planning_components_visualizer.cpp](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/move_arm/html/planning__components__visualizer_8cpp.html) in the [move_arm](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm) package:

**Joint Markers:**
Look in [createSelectableJointMarker](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/move_arm/html/classPlanningComponentsVisualizer.html#abd2840357b7085ac4ba190c67e9aaaaf).  In particular, the scale is set using the `maxDimension` parameter.  For joints with mesh geometry, this is calculated based on the mesh vertex location with some odd assumptions.  For other joints (with cylinder/box geometry), the scale is set to a fixed value.  It looks like all markers should have a scale in the range of 0.15 to 0.5.

**End-Effector Marker:**
It's a little less clear how the end-effector marker is generated.  I believe this is also created in the same file.  It looks like it's related to the `PlanningComponentsVisualizer::EndEffectorControl` type and the `makeInteractive6DOFMarker` topic.  Perhaps this marker is always created with a fixed size of 0.225.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2013-06-19**:
Good enough, must say that markers do really tend to be too small sometimes though. But that's another problem :). Thanks.